# autoupdate bigquery table file from GCS in parquet format

Tags: amazon-s3, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, parquet

I have used the datatransfer table that will automatically send data from a s3 bucket to GCS. This transfer will be run everyday automatically in the morning.
I created a table in bigquery that will read the data from the GCS , so far no problem.
Now my concern is even though the files update on a daily basis on the GCS the bigquery table that is suppose to consume the GCS parquet file don't seem to update everyday.

What is the procedure for the table to be able to consume the latest data on the GCS bucket.

Example I created my table on the 17 April .

[image]

My data transfer send some file on the 19

[image]

But when i do a `select max(created_at) from mytable` 
it doesn't give me the last updated data

Comment: Is the table is external table ?

Comment: Hey, are you still seeing the behavior?